# How to complete a table of values of an exponential function?

Tags: probability, exponential-function, exponential-distribution

I got this question from my teacher and I tried to solve but no luck!
the question given is:

> Toss 100 pennies and remove all of the ‘heads’. Toss the remaining
>   pennies, and again, remove all heads. Repeat this process until all
>   coins have been removed.
>
> A. Record the number of pennies tossed for each trial in a table.
>
> \begin{array}{|l|l|}
> \hline
> \text{Number of trial} & \text{Number of pennies tossed} \\
> \hline
> 1               & 100 \\
> 2               & \\
> 3               & \\
> 4               & \\
> 5               & \\
> 6               & \\
> 7               & \\
> 8               & \\
> 9               & \\
> 10              & \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
>
> B. Graph the data and draw a smooth curve through the points.
>
> C. Explain why this data can be modeled by an exponential function.

Based on what I know, we should use the general form of an exponential function which is $y=a\cdot b^x + c$

I think C, in this case, is 100

and from the pattern, we can divide the second value of Y by the first value of Y then we get the common ratio that can help to complete the table of value.

In this question, I have only one Y-value!

Comment: It seems (from your transcription of the assignment) that the table of values should be completed by experiment, not by mathematical reasoning...

Comment: At each step in the process, we should expect that the amount will *approximately* be halved.  I would expect it to act much more like $100(\frac{1}{2})^n$.  You should be able to convince yourself of this using an argument related to expected value.  (*To see the expected number of coins remaining after the second flip for example, pretend that we begin with 100 coins and flip each coin twice in succession, regardless of whether or not a head was flipped.  Keep only the coins that flipped tails twice in a row*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "record" means that you should *observe* what happens and write it down, not try to predict it. Indeed, notice that there *isn't* any way to predict the first new value - you can't predict how many pennies will come down heads unless you try it and see!

The problem seems to be literally asking you to flip 100 pennies, remove the ones that come up heads, and repeat, writing down the results as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Why not follow the instructions?

This is a physical experiment, which includes documenting and analyzing your observations, fitting them to a mathematical model.

Your general function seems to be
$$
y(x) = a \cdot b^x
$$

Think about using a half logarithmic plot ($x$ vs $\log y$) so you can interpolate with a simple straight line.